# Plot solution of equation with shift

Tags: plotting

For example I have an equation $F[x,y]==0$.

Let $S$ is a set of solutions of equation. $(a,b) \in S \leftrightarrow F[a,b]=0$.

I wanna draw a set $\{(a,b) + \operatorname{grad} F (a,b) : (a,b) \in S\}$, how can I do that?

For example I have

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1; 
G[x,y]:={2x,2y} 
y1[x]=Sqrt[1-x^2] 
y2[x]=-Sqrt[1-x^2] 
ParametricPlot[{{t, y1[t]} + G[t, y1[t]], {t, y2[t]} + G[t, y2[t]]}, {t, -1, 1}]
```

There are

$G=\operatorname{grad} F(x,y)$,

$y1,y2$ — solutions of $F(x,y)=0$.

But in some cases I dont know how to solve $F(x,y)=0$ and find $y1,y2$. For example in case $F(x,y)=xlnx−y$

Comment: Why I mixing different spaces? $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $\operatorname{grad}F(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: How can I arrange the code? «'code'» doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest edit:

```
ClearAll[x, y, F, g]
F[x_, y_] := Sin[x]/Sqrt[x] + Cos[Sqrt[y]]/ArcTan[y]
g[x_, y_] = Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}]


Manipulate[
 Show[
    #,
    # /. p : {_Real, _Real} :> p + t g @@ p /. Blue -> Red

    ] &@ContourPlot[F[x, y] == 0
   , {x, 1, 20}, {y, 0, 10}, BaseStyle -> {Thickness@.01}, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue
   ],
 {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

---

For convolved case you can try this way:

```
ClearAll[x, y, F, g]
F[x_, y_] := x Log[x] - y
g[x_, y_] = Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}]

Show[
   #,  (* condition below:  /; p[[1]] > 0 should be skipped, here it is because of Log*)
   # /. p : {_Real, _Real} :> p + g @@ p /; p[[1]] > 0 /. Blue -> Red

   ] &@ContourPlot[F[x, y] == 0, {x, -10, 15}, {y, -2, 15}, 
                   BaseStyle -> {Thickness@.01}, ContourStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Here we were working just on graphics points.

---

Simple case:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 1;
g[x, y] = Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}];
{sol1[x_], sol2[x_]} = y /. Solve[F[x, y] == 0, {x, y}]

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{
   {x, sol1[x]},
   {x, sol1[x]} + g[x, sol1[x]],
   {x, sol2[x]},
   {x, sol2[x]} + g[x, sol2[x]]
   }
  , {x, -1, 1}, BaseStyle -> {Thickness@.01}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Lighter@Blue, Red, Lighter@Red}
  ],
 StreamPlot[g[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamStyle -> Thin]
 ]
```

> [image]

Comment: Yes thanks a lot! But when I compile your code in my computer I have only inner circle, without outer circle and streamplot. Do not know why?

Comment: @kp9r4d I don't know try to reset the kernel maybe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for second listing! But when I change F[x_,y_]=xLox[x]-y on F[x_,y_]=x^2+y^2-1 I have very strange result. On your computer its all ok?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Last 2 questions
1) Your method works for irrational equations like F[x,y]=Sin[x]/Sqrt[x]+Cos[Sqrt[y]]/Arctan[y] ?
2) I want to draw function $(a,b)+t \operatorname{grad}F$ and manipulate $t$. But I cant see how to change your code to do this. Can you do this?
I want something like that:

Comment: Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{x,sol[x]}+t*g[x,sol[x]],{x,-2,2}],{t,0,1}]

Comment: @kp9r4d Ok, take a look at the edit. Now I'm going to sleep, good luck.

Comment: Thanks! You are really help me! I'll help you, too, when I will learn mathematica! :3